# javascript / lodash : how to do a recursive deep get in an object thanks to a sub tree object

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

Let's say I have a deep object like this

```
cont obj = { 
   a0: { 
     b0: { 
       c0: 0, 
       c1: 1 
      }, 
      b1: { 
       c2: 2
      } 
     }
 }
```

and I want in one single method to retrieve a sub tree of it with this kind of api, let's name it 'retrieveDeep' :

```
const subObj = retrieveDeep(
 obj,
 {
  a0: {
    b0: {
      c0: null
    },
    b1: {
      c2: null
    }
  }
 } 
)
// should return 
// { 
//   a0: { 
//     b0: { 
//       c0: 0
//      }, 
//      b1: { 
//       c2: 2
//      } 
//     }
// }
```

I know actually that I could implement that from scratch with not so much difficulties, but if there is already a lodash (or even it looks like a bit the graphQL api shape!) function, I would happy to know it
tx

Comment: I just used here the value 'null' as a targeting placeholder (this is an arbitrary choice), to be replaced by the true value that is matching the corresponding key... So it is replaced by an object, a number, a string... it depends just in the corresponding value in the source object.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing for yet, actually I could write the recursive function in 10 minutes, but just I wanted to be sure that there is no sync about this question, and already a specific shared function in the community :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the properties of the pattern and make recursive calls for objects. Assign primitive values.

```js
function retrieveDeep(object, pattern) {
    function iter(o, p, r) {
        Object.keys(p).forEach(function (k) {
            if (k in o) {
                if (typeof o[k] === 'object' && o[k] !== null) {
                    r[k] = {};
                    iter(o[k], p[k], r[k]);
                    return;
                }
                r[k] = o[k];
            }
        });
    }
    
    var result = {};
    iter(object, pattern, result);
    return result;
}

var obj = { a0: { b0: { c0: 0, c1: 1 }, b1: { c2: 2 } } },
    subObj = retrieveDeep(obj, { a0: { b0: { c0: null }, b1: { c2: null } } });

console.log(subObj);
```

Comment: Cool tx ! And I have just actually replaced the condition `if (typeof o[k] === 'object')` by `if (p[k] !== null)` to actually also get the possible nested objects, arrays if we want also.

Answer (score 1):

With lodash 1+, there is a shortest way using **_.at(object, [paths])** :

```js
let exist = {
  a:{
    b: {c: 3}
  }, 
  ZZ: 2
};
    
let resExist = _.at(exist, 'a.b.c').pop() // => 3

let notExit = { a : 1 }
    
let resNoExist = _.at(notExit, 'a.b.c').pop() // undefined
    
console.log('resExist', resExist)
console.log('resNoExist', resNoExist)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

see [documention](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#at)

Answer (score 0):

### Lodash [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) method: `_.get(object, path, [defaultValue])`

```
var object = { 
  'a': [
    { 
      'b': { 
        'c': 3 
      } 
    }
  ] 
};
 
_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3
 
_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3
 
_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default
```